# How do I expand <tr> width or combine <td> cells in this css / jquery widget?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using a fantasy football website with this custom widget.

[Site is here](http://www5.myfantasyleague.com/2015/home/64460#7), [css is here](http://www5.myfantasyleague.com/fflnetdynamic2015/64460_use_css.css), though there's plenty of other CSS being inherited.

I'd like all the icons displayed horizontally within the top row of the table.

I have set up a row for the icons, but they're still forced within a narrow column, each icon appearing to own its own row.  My best guess is that it's this "function createColumnLeft(fpid)" part of the widget code:

```
function createColumnLeft(fpid)
{
    var htmlComponent_s = '<table>';
    var htmlComponent_e = '</table>';
    var temoComp = '';
    for(var i=0;fpid!=null && i<fpid.length ;i++) {
        if(!(middleFranchise!='' && fpid[i].id == middleFranchise)) {
            var fdb = franchiseDatabase['fid_'+fpid[i].id];
            if(fdb instanceof Franchise) {
                temoComp += '<td class="left_m" id="left_menu_'+fdb.id+'">';
                var displayName = '';
                 if(useIcons) {
                    temoComp+='<td>';
                 if(fdb.icon == null || fdb.icon.trim() == '') {
                    displayName = fdb.name;
                 }
                 else {
                    displayName = '<img src="' + fdb.icon + '"class="franchiseicon" title="' + fdb.name + '" />'
                 }
              } 
              else {
                  temoComp+='<td class="teamname">';
                  displayName   =   fdb.name;
              }
            temoComp = temoComp + '<a href="javascript:populateSelectedFranchise(\''+fdb.id+'\')">' + displayName +'</a>' ;
            temoComp = temoComp + '</td></tr>';
            }
        }
    }
    return htmlComponent_s+temoComp+htmlComponent_e;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#roster_column_left table tbody tr {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it doesn't seem like a CSS problem. It looks like the code above is creating a new row for each array element.

htmlComponent_s & htmlComponent_e are beginning and terminating  tags, and because there's a terminating  tag in this line:

```
temoComp    =    temoComp + '</td></tr>';
```

... that's causing the DOM parser to assume that you meant one row per icon. You really need to be explicitly creating a row, then creating a  per icon.